# How can i find IEvolution2 version 4.4.0.0

Tags: c#

> Could not load file or assembly 'IEvolution2, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4ab65cf407ad1e2b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'IEvolution2, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4ab65cf407ad1e2b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'IEvolution2, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4ab65cf407ad1e2b'

1. first, what is `IEvolution2`?  this error is throw out when i use "sessionPrint()" method, it's included in NiceLabel.SDK, and
2. stack information is :

   > at a.d.a.i.f.a()
   >       at a.d.a.i.f.SessionPrint(ISessionPrintInitializer sessionPrintInitializer)
   >       at NiceLabel.SDK.SessionPrintRequest.a(Int32 A_0, ISolutionRuntime A_1)
   >       at NiceLabel.SDK.Label.SessionPrint(Int32 quantity, ISessionPrintRequest sessionPrintRequest)

I use the "SDK.NET.Interface.dll" for this method.

- do you have any suggestions?

i think this problem is related to windows dll, but i can't find this dll in MSDN, so i am confused.

Comment: In google. When you search, also include names of third party libraries you use, that might invoke this error.

Comment: thanks for updating your question

Answer (score 0):

A short google reveals `IEvolution2` is part of the [ImageEn](https://www.imageen.com/)* image processing library. I assume you are using it. Try to reinstall the library, or otherwise seek help from the company that produces it. It is paid, so they should give you support.

---

* https://www.imageen.com/ieforum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=1698